# Spring integration 'No poller' exception

Tags: spring-integration

After excluding

```
 <exclusion>
     <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream</artifactId>
 </exclusion>
```

I am getting error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No poller has been defined for Annotation-based endpoint, and no
> default poller is available within the context

I have just **one** `QueueChannel` (also have `MessageAggregator` - might be acting as queue?), and few `PublishSubscribeChannel`

Anyway **without exclusion**  works fine.

What could be the issue? Why exclusion of dependency spring-cloud-stream causes this?

Answer (score 0):

Because Spring Cloud Stream creates a `PollerMetadata` bean with the `PollerMetadata.DEFAULT_POLLER` name for us. for its own purpose and for convenience and according Spring Cloud conventions.

Spring Integration by itself doesn't do any convenience assumptions and doesn't create a default poller for us.

You just need to go into your `@Configuration` and specify there a `PollerMetadata` with respective trigger for polling logic. Otherwise you can configure a local poller for that `MessageAggregator`  endpoint which consumes from the mentioned `QueueChannel`.

See docs for more info: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/messaging-endpoints.html#endpoint-pollingconsumer